# Will Unity 2D continue using metacity or will it use compiz?

Tags: compiz, 11.10, unity-2d

[I've heard](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTQxOQ) that Unity-2D will be using Compiz in 11.10 - is that correct?

Comment: That does not make too much sense since the -2D variant is for non-3D computers. Compiz is usually used as a compositor, not as a WM. I do not see the point in using Compiz as a non-compositing WM.

Comment: @queueoverflow, this doesn't make any sense to me  either - hence why I asked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to packages dependencies, this is not true: http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/unity-2d